# How do you avoid streamlit side bar listing all function before rendering the actual sidebar?

Tags: streamlit

After upgrading my streamlit app from 1.14 to current release, some unwanted options were added the side bar (listing all scripts with streamlit code) above the actual sidebar content.

How can i remove this sidebar section ?

I expected that upgrade will not change the sidebar behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to remove the side navigation bar containing file names in the latest version of streamlit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543675/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-side-navigation-bar-containing-file-names-in-the-la)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. You can pass --hideSidebarNav True arg and the addition is disabled